# sqlalchemy determine which items in a database have changed

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a MySQL database created by flask-sqlalchemy running on a remote server. This database has many users saved to it.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)  # type: int
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)  # type: str
```

I would like to connect to this database periodically and cache the changes locally. Is there a built-in way to determine which items have been added or updated or should I manually implement a mod-time or version on each object?

Comment: The equivalent of "get all from where id not yet in local" ? or do user change as well?

Comment: @PatrickArtner user changes as well, ie the username changes